# argocd repo add not using proxy

Tags: proxy, argocd, gitops

I am running Argocd in a private cluster in AKS and I am trying to connect to a git repo that is behind a proxy. When I try to add the repo using the `--proxy` flag it doesn't seem to try to connect via proxy. The domain doesn't even resolve and when I swap out with the `IP` address the connection just timeouts. I am not convinced the `repo add` command is using the proxy command at all.

I have validated that I can access the proxy with no issue but for some reason `argocd repo add` isn't using it.

Maybe there is someone out there who has run across a similar issue?

With url (not actual)

```
argocd repo add ssh://git@xyz.com:7999/clouds.git --proxy http://proxy:3128 --ssh-private-key-path ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
FATA[0000] rpc error: code = Unknown desc = error testing repository connectivity: dial tcp: lookup xyz.com on 10.0.0.10:53: no such host
```

```
argocd repo add ssh://git@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:7999/clouds.git --ssh-private-key-path ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 --proxy http://proxy:3128
FATA[0060] rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded
```